# Take a word and print it out in the shape of a triangle as shown below - Parameters and methods

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Thanks for taking the time to check out my question. I have to write some code in Dr. Java that takes in a word and then prints it out in a specific pattern. Basically here are some examples:

```
Input: fishy
Output: f 
        fifi 
        fisfisfis 
        fishfishfishfish 
        fishyfishyfishyfishyfishy
```

Basically, I'm just adding another character to the previous one and printing it out that many number of times.

Here is my attempt at my solution:

```
String wordcopy = word; 
   int size = wordcopy.length();
   for (int i=1; i<=size; i+=1)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(word.substring(0,j+1));
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }}
```

I have already set up my parameters so that's fine. The only thing I seem to be missing is the method itself that prints out what it's supposed to. Can anyone please help me with this problem and how I can go from here? 
Thanks!

Comment: replace word.substring(0,j+1) with word.substring(0,i) in the inner loop

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was something that small.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `word.substring(0,j+1)` with `word.substring(0,i)`:

```
    String wordcopy = word;
    int size = wordcopy.length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i += 1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(word.substring(0, i));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

There are some cleanup things you can do. For instance, this code yields the same result:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(word.substring(0, i));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it.